# Video Playback Freezes - Mojave 10.14

Tags: video, mac-mini, mojave

I'm using a Mac mini (late 2012) with Mojave 10.14, and I'm having issues with video playback.

After using the Mac to play back videos, whether that's online streaming/YouTube or IINA/VLC video files playback - after about 8-10 minutes of use it freezes for a few seconds, than continues without any issues for another 8-10 minutes, freezes again, and so on.

The same behavior is observed while playing videos from internal HDD or DASD.

Needless to say, it was perfectly fine under High Sierra (same apps, and content).

I use Internet cable connection (up to 150 Mbps download speed, and up to 15 Mbps upload speed) exclusively, WiFi is OFF. Hardware configuration: RAM: 2 x 8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4000 - VRAM: 1536 MB Display: HP ZR30w 2560 x 1600 Resource usage while playing video: RAM: Physical memory 16.00 GB Memory used 8.71 GB Cashed files 7.28 GB Swap used 1.96 GB CPU: System: 2.27% User: 3.94% Idle: 93.99%

Please help!

Comment: Please describe the freezing - is the whole player freezing and you can't manipulate any of the controls or is it just the video itself?  Also, try booting into Safe Mode to see if something is being loaded that is causing issues.

Comment: @Allan: it is just the video itself freezes, all controls stay responsive. I can see nothing out of the ordinary among the loaded soft (from EntreCheck report).

Comment: If the video is freezing while rendering, it could be a hardware issue.  Try booting into safe mode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Allan: no freezing in safe mode. Can we conclude at this stage it is a software-related issue, and not a hardware-related one, please? If the answer is "yes", what should be done to find the culprit(s)?

Comment: Have seen similar issues with Kodi. There appears to be  a bug with the hardware rendering libs. If you disable hardware rendering in your player, CPU usage will go up, but video hangs will go down. I'm still seeing some micro stuttering. Probably safe mode won't even load the libs for hardware video decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different browser (Firefox) or a different media player (VLC or MPlayer X)and see if this happens. I am assuming that you are using Safari and QuickTime Player.